# How do I do dependency injection with service in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

How do I do dependency injection with service?

I got the typescript notification:

> [Angular] Can't resolve all parameters for LandingComponent in 
>   landing.component.ts:
>   ([object Object], ?).

---

**Update**

I shouldn't do just use LangService in constructor like this:

> private _langService: LangService;

Because LangService is a implementation. In real case there will be few implementations like LangMockedSerives, langService_01, langService_02. Thereby landing component should know nothig about implementation and work with interfaces only.

---

**Service and it's interface**

```js
export interface ILangService {
}

export class LangService implements ILangService {
}
```

**Component**

```js
import { ILangService } from '../../services/Ilang.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-landing',
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./landing.component.less']
})

export class LandingComponent {
    private langService: ILangService
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        _langService: ILangService;
    ) {
        this._langService = langService;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { ILangService } from './services/Ilang.service';
import { LangService } from './services/Lang.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
    ], { useHash: false }),
  ],
  providers: [
    LangService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: In your landing component, you just have to do `private _langService: langService;` that's it and remove all those extra stuff

Comment: @Suryan LangService is a implementation. In real case there will be few implementations like LangMockedSerives, langService_01, langService_02. Thereby landing component should know nothig about implementation and work with interfaces only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated Answer

If you want to use different implementations for the same service you should create an [InjectionToken<T>](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) and provide the right implementation for your interface in your module declarations.

**Interface - lang.service.ts**

Create an injection token that will be recognized by the injector typed with `ILangService` interface

```js
export const LangService = new InjectionToken<ILangService>('LangService');

export interface ILangService { }
```

**1st module - english.module.ts**

Provide `EnglishLangService` for the `LangService` injection token where `EnglishLangService` implements `ILangService` interface

```js
import { LangService } from './services/lang.service';
import { EnglishLangService } from './services/english-lang.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ LandingComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LangService, useClass: EnglishLangService }
  ]
})
export class EnglishModule { }
```

**2nd module - french.module.ts**

Provide `FrenchLangService` for the `LangService` injection token where `FrenchLangService` implements `ILangService` interface

```js
import { LangService } from './services/lang.service';
import { FrenchLangService } from './services/french-lang.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ LandingComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LangService, useClass: FrenchLangService }
  ]
})
export class FrenchModule { }
```

**Component - landing.component.ts**

This way you can inject `LangService` in your component and the injector will retrieve the implementation provided in your module

```js
import { LangService } from '../../services/lang.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-landing',
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./landing.component.less']
})
export class LandingComponent {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private langService: LangService,
    ) { }
}
```

**Testing - mock-lang.service.ts**

When testing you will be able to provide your mock implementation the same way you provide the right implementation in your application modules

```js
import { LangService } from './services/lang.service';
import { MockLangService } from './services/mock-lang.service';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: LangService, useClass: MockLangService },
  ],
});
```

## Original Answer

You should import your service with the class instead of the interface

```js
import { LangService } from '../../services/lang.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-landing',
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./landing.component.less']
})
export class LandingComponent {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private langService: LangService;
    ) { }
}
```

Also don't forget to set the `@Injectable()` decorator on your service class declaration

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LangService implements ILangService { }
```

And of course, you have to provide the service to your module

```js
import { LangService } from './services/Lang.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [
    LangService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*You can read about Angular Dependency Injection here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection*

*Another interesting link for advance service declarations: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/08/17/using-useclass-usefactory-usevalue-useexisting-with-treeshakable-providers-in-angular/*

Comment: LangService is a implementation. In real case there will be few implementations like LangMockedSerives, langService_01, langService_02. Thereby landing component should know nothig about implementation and work with interfaces only.

Answer (score 0):

### service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

export interface ILangService {
}

 @Injectable()   
export class LangService implements ILangService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  <-- httpclient for angular6
  }

getData(): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.get('https://..../');
.map(this.extractData)
 .catch(this.handleError);
 }

private extractData(res: Response) {
const body = res.json();
return body || [];
}

private handleError(error: any) {
const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
console.error(errMsg);
console.log('Error....!');
 return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
}
```

### Component:-

```
import { LangService } from '../../services/lang.service'; <-- Import sevice here

@Component({
selector: 'app-landing',
templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./landing.component.less']
})

 export class LandingComponent {
constructor(
private http: HttpClient,
_langService: LangService  <--- service
) { }

ngOnInit() {
let thisx = this;
this._langService.getData().subscribe(
function (success) {
// alert here on success
alert (success);
},
 error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + 
JSON.stringify(error)));
}
}
```

Comment: LangService is a implementation. In real case there will be few implementations like LangMockedSerives, langService_01, langService_02. Thereby landing component should know nothig about implementation and work with interfaces only.

Answer (score 0):

LangService shoul be removed from app.module.ts providers:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
    ], { useHash: false }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And interface should be added to providers in component:

```
import { LangService } from '../../services/Lang.service';
import { ILangService } from '../../services/ILang.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-landing',
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./landing.component.less'],
    providers: [
        { provide: ILangService, useClass: LangService }
    ]
})

export class LandingComponent {
    private langService: ILangService
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        _langService: ILangService;
    ) {
        this._langService = langService;
    }
}
```